# MyBatis returns single element instead of list

Tags: java, mybatis

I'm having a problem with gathering data from database using MyBatis. I have three java objects and three database tables respectively. My problem is that MyBatis returns element itself instead of List with this element. So I get Argument Type Mismatch exception.

CalendarDto.java

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CalendarDto {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Holiday> holidays;
    private List<WorkDay> workDays;
}
```

Holiday.java

```
public record Holiday(long id, LocalDate date, HolidayType dateType){
}
```

WorkDay.java

```
public record WorkDay(long id, long day, int hourFrom, int hourTo) {
}
```

CalendarMapper.java

```
@Mapper
public interface CalendarMapper {
    CalendarDto getForCabinet(@Param("cabinetId") long cabinetId);
}
```

CalendarMapper.xml

```
<select id="getForCabinet" resultMap="cabinetMapping">
        select c.id calendar_id ,
               c."name" calendar_name,
               h.id holiday_id,
               h."date" holiday_date,
               h.date_type holiday_date_type,
               wt.id work_time_id,
               wt."day" "day",
               wt.hour_from work_time_from,
               wt.hour_to work_time_to
        from cabinets cb
                 join calendar c on (cb.calendar_id = c.id)
                 join work_time wt on (c.id = wt.calendar_id)
                 left join holiday h on (c.id = h.calendar_id)
        where cb.id = #{cabinetId}
    </select>

    <resultMap id="cabinetMapping" type="ru.zikasak.roombookerbot.domain.CalendarDto">
        <id column="calendar_id" property="id"/>
        <result column="calendar_name" property="name"/>
        <collection property="holidays" ofType="ru.zikasak.roombookerbot.domain.Holiday"
                    column="holiday_id">
            <result property="id" column="holiday_id"/>
            <result column="holiday_date" property="date"/>
            <result column="holiday_date_type" property="dateType"/>
        </collection>
        <collection property="workDays" ofType="ru.zikasak.roombookerbot.domain.WorkDay"
       column="work_time_id" javaType="ArrayList">
            <result property="id" column="work_time_id"/>
            <result property="day" column="day"/>
            <result column="work_time_from" property="hourFrom"/>
            <result column="work_time_to" property="hourTo"/>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
```

Comment: What if you omit `column="holiday_id"` and `column="work_time_id"` from the `collection` nodes so only keeping `property` and `ofType`?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to use the `@AllArgsConstructor` with the list.  The first record only has a single `Calendar`, `Holiday`, `Workday`.  Try to use a `@RequiredArgsConstructor(access=PACKAGE)` without the lists defined, so that it can create the `Calendar` and then add the created `Holiday` and `Workday` while it parses rows.